# Mapping yaml file contents to a list in python

Tags: python, list, mapping

I have a yaml file with the below structure:

this is test.yaml

```
    server:
      - host: ubuntu
        ip: 10.20.30.40
        path: /var/log/syslog
      - host: ubuntu
        ip: 10.20.3.50
        path: /var/log/syslog
```

When I call in my python script,I load the yaml file and parse the contents. I cannot iterate all the contents though:

How can I create a list in the below format:

```
    import yaml



    def read_yaml(file):
        with open(file, "r") as stream:
            try:
                config = yaml.load(stream)
                print("inside the function")
                # print(config)
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)
                print("\n")
        return config

    d = read_yaml("config.yaml")


    print('{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(*d['server']))
```

I want an output with host@ip:path for the different servers in the yaml file. But the command above does not work and generates an error: TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list 
or
KeyError:Host

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You unpack a list (`d['server']`)  as an argument to `format`. But format wants named keyword arguments (kwargs) in this case.

Since you should only hope to print 1 item in each such `print` call you have, try:

```
for item in d['server']:
    print('{host}@{ip}:{path}'.format(**item))
```